# Round the edges of a closed path in d3 donut chart

Tags: svg, d3.js

I created a donut chart using d3's pie command. I added padding for the slices and now I need to round the edges of the arcs so that they match the design.

I tried using path stroke but that only works for open paths and in this case the path is closed.

I think I need to modify the function that draws the path itself. I'm looking for a guidance how to do it

Answer (score 0):

D3 arc has a config option called 'cornerRadius'. It rounds the edges of the arcs.

https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arc_cornerRadius

To use it I just needed to add that option to arc generator.

```js
arcGen = arc()
    .cornerRadius(2)
    .innerRadius(this.innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(this.outerRadius);
```